# Echo data from database using PHP no errors but data will not show

Tags: php, database, echo

I am currently working on a page for a local football team. I want to be able to insert the player information into a my database and then echo the data back onto the page for each player. I have created this code however there is no sign of any of my HTML coding being echoed back to me on the page. If anyone could help with this it'd be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_u14team");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    $name = $rows['name'];
    $position = $rows['position'];
    $age = $rows['age'];
    $height = $rows['height'];
    $biography = $rows['biography'];
    $image = $rows['image'];

    echo '<div id="teammember"> 
        <img src="'.$image.'" />
        p>Name:'.$name.'</br>
        Position:'.$position.'</br>
        Age:'.$age.'</br>
        Height:'.$height.'</br>
        Biography:'.$biography.'</p>                                        
    </div>';

endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Probably have PHP 5.6 installed and the dropped `mysql_*` is throwing a fatal (I'm guessing. I've not tried using `mysql_*` in a PHP 5.6 environment)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑI'm using 5.4 so I don't think thats the issue? I'm quite baffled right now!

Comment: Silly question; but have you established a connection to your database successfully?

Comment: Yes, if the connection isn't established it kills all pages on the site... @ʰᵈˑ Getting this error currently `[04-Sep-2014 04:50:54 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home2/localbu6/public_html/dafcyouth/u14s.php on line 14
`

Comment: Does your user have `SELECT` privileges on the database? Does the table `tbl_u14team` exist? Add `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of `mysql_query`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.. for both of those questions the answer is yes. Everything appears to be error-free.. @ʰᵈˑ

Comment: What did `mysql_error()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [04-Sep-2014 04:50:54 America/Denver] **PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given** in /home2/localbu6/public_html/dafcyouth/u14s.php on line 14

This means your query has failed.

> *For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.*

Since the error is complaining about a `boolean`, (and `FALSE`being a boolean and only returned if the query failed) - your query **has** failed.

Replace your `mysql_query` line with the following and take the necessary actions

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_u14team") or die(mysql_error());
```

- Does your MySQL user have `SELECT` privileges on the database you're connected to?

  - And `SELECT` privileges on the table?
- Does the table `tbl_u14team` exist?
- Has your MySQL connection been disconnected before this code hits?

Comment: Really confused now. Getting the table doesnt exist error however the table does exist 100% but if you look `Table 'localbu6_dafcyouth._tbl_u14team' doesn't exist` We have a '.' before my table extension...? @ʰᵈˑ

Comment: What is the name of the database that `tbl_u14team` belongs to?

Comment: _dafcyouth so I'm not sure whats happened here.

Comment: Replace your query with `SELECT * FROM _dafcyouth.tbl_u14team`

Comment: Now being told I have no permissions to SELECT from the table, even though I specifically set my permissions to do just that..

Comment: Redo the permissions, and that should do it

Comment: Resolved, the server was functioning incorrectly toward the end of my problem. One thing after another haha. Thank you.

Comment: Ah haha, glad it's sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `var_Dump(mysql_fetch_array($query));` before the `while` to see it the content array is as expected. Or do a `var_Dump($rows)` within the while.